# How to update single text label in D3js enter-update-exit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, d3.js, visualization

I've been using the D3js cookbook, and the following example code to create a [doughnutChart](https://github.com/NickQiZhu/d3-cookbook/blob/master/src/chapter9/pie-chart.html).

The question I had was with regards to the labels.

At present, I use the following:

```
function renderLabels() {
    var labels = _pieG.selectAll("text.total").data(_data);

    labels.enter()
        .append("text")
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("class", "inside")
        .attr("class", "total");

    labels.transition()
        .text(function(d) {
            var total = 0;
            for (var j = 0; j < _data.length; j++) {
                total = total + _data[j].count + _data[j].abnormal;
            }
            return total;
        });
}
```

Which renders a total value in the centre of the chart. The issue is, that it actually renders one total in the centre of the chart for every datapoint, rather than one single text label. I'm not sure how to just get a single datapoint label. See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0pw9tp4f/) for a working example. What I want is to have a single label, rather than the three:

```
<text dy=".35em" class="total" style="text-anchor: middle;">17</text>
<text dy=".35em" class="total" style="text-anchor: middle;">17</text>
<text dy=".35em" class="total" style="text-anchor: middle;">17</text>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Well the hacky version would be to simply pass in the first data element (http://jsfiddle.net/0pw9tp4f/1/), but it sounds like you'd want to refactor the code to not use selections for the label and instead have a single element for it whose text is set on update (as opposed to also checking whether to add/remove/reposition labels).

Comment: What Lars said. Create a separate function just to add the total. Call it on your renderLabels() update.